# How to show easily that $X^4+8$ is irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is there an easy way to show that $X^4+8$ is irreducible ? I was thinking aboute finding a $a$ such that I can use the Eisenstein criterion  $(X+a)^4+8$, but I don't find a such $a$.

Comment: i hope you tried $a=1$...

Comment: irreducible over what?

Comment: of course I tried $a=1$ but I get $(X+1)^4+8=X^4+4X^3+6X^2+4X+9$ and so, I can't use Eisenstein criterion. I'm looking the irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Good that you have tried.... I do not have any hope that it would work for $a=1$ and not even for any integer... I said it just because it should be done as a first step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If you wish to prove irreducibility with respect to the rationals, use the following theorem with $p = 5$.

Let $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and let $p$ be a prime integer which does not divide $a_n$.  If the residue $\overline{f}$ of $f$ modulo $p$ is irreducible, then $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

Following idea does not work always but....

- Try to find roots of $x^4+8$...

I hope you got the point... I do not want to spoil the fun...

Comment: $(x^2+1)^2$ has no root in the rationals, but it's reducible nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg :  I do not mean having no rational roots imply irreducibility... Once you know the roots it does not take much time to see what are the only possible combinations that comes in a possible factor...

Comment: @downvoter : can you tell me what makes you to down vote this??

Answer (score 0):

Polynomials of this type are easily factorizable over the reals:
$$
X^4+8=X^4+2\sqrt{8}X^2+(\sqrt{8})^2-2\sqrt{8}X^2
=(X^2+\sqrt{8})^2-(\sqrt[4]{32}X)^2
$$
The discriminant of $X^2\pm2\sqrt[4]{2}X+2\sqrt{2}$ is
$$
4\sqrt{2}-8\sqrt{2}<0
$$
so…

Comment: I'm not suppose to use the discriminant

Comment: @idm Why not? It just shows that the two factors are irreducible over the reals.

Comment: Because it's an exercise in Galois theory, and the discriminant is not introduced yet (it's the next chapter).

Comment: @idm The discriminant of degree two polynomials was discovered by Al-Khwarizmi about 1200 years ago, much earlier than Galois theory, and is taught in secondary school.

Comment: Anyways... I just can't use it !

Comment: @idm Then rewrite the polynomials by completing the square, putting them in the form $(x+a)^2+b$, with $b>0$. Example: $x^2+x+1=(x+\frac14)^2+\frac34$.

Comment: what does it mean ?